Caption color in Beamer presentation with `caption` package
I'm using caption package for customizing the look of caption in my figures:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{default}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={small},labelfont=small,name=Fig.,labelfont={color=blue}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \caption{Test}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

Which produces:

How can I customize caption to inherit from original caption color without caption package? Like this:

color=blue does not give original blue color. I found this cheatsheet on the Internet: https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf, I thought I could use color=caption, but that does not work either.

caption is the colour of the caption text, Figure: is coloured with the caption name colour. The default beamer colour theme uses a blended blue for this, which is defined as \definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}.
\documentclass{beamer}

% making beamer colours available for caption package
\usebeamercolor{caption}
\usebeamercolor{caption name}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={small,color=caption.fg},labelfont=small,name=Fig.,labelfont={color=caption name.fg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you very much!

@RuslanPopov You're welcome! And thanks for adding the missing pieces to the code in your question!
